# HTML/Javscript - number input to accept other radixes than 10

Tags: javascript, string, input, numbers, radix

One of the things about `<input type="number">` is that on desktop PCs, pressing (you can also hold them for continuous triggering) UP or DOWN on the arrow keys on the keyboard increments or decrements the number by what is defined by "step" (if not defined, it just +/- the value by 1), most browsers (firefox and chrome) even have the <kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd> buttons on the right side of the number input you can click with the mouse. However, there is one problem: the `number input` doesn't support other `radixes` besides `base-10`.

I resorted to use `<input type="text">` since it's the only way (as far as I know, prove me if I'm wrong) for the user to enter a string of text that isn't “numbers only” (digits 0-9, “-” for negative numbers, “.” for decimal fractions, <kbd>E</kbd> for exponent for scientific notation). The problem however, is that does not work like the number input (<kbd>up</kbd> / <kbd>down</kbd> just moves the text cursor to the start/end of the line).

How do I have an input that the user can not only type in characters into the textbox, but also increment/decrement a number of a different `radix`? I'm making a simple JS HTML file that lets you convert a given integer (`BigInt`) to all other `radixes` (enters hex, fills other input text boxes with the same number with a different `radix`), and I really dislike that only the decimal number is the only one you can increment/decrement with. This is very useful for programmers alike when especially debugging when most debuggers don't display decimal or binary (when dealing with `bitwise-based` information and you are reading the byte value of that), making it somewhat annoying to grab a calculator and convert `radixes`.

Comment: "*I really dislike that only the decimal number is the only one you can increment/decrement with.*" in fairness, using non-decimal numbers would be for the *extreme* minority. Even among programmers and scientists using 1. an HTML `number` input 2. with a defined `step` 3. where the base of the number is not 10; is not that common. The vast majority of use cases for validation would be for the most common base: 10.

Comment: Still, it would be trivial to have a custom input where the base is custom (keep the numeric source, convert to base `n` for display), up/down increment/decrement (event listeners for up/down modifying the source) and you have something like a `+` and `-` button performing the same functionality. There might be plugins that do that already.

Comment: lol sorry you don't like it, but yes. Easily translating between radixes requires turning them into strings. `Number.toString( radix )`. To change them back use `parseInt(Number, radix)`. This question is asking a lot though. If you want more help be more specific and give it a shot yourself.

Comment: You may find [this article](https://medium.com/coderscorner/number-systems-decimal-binary-octal-and-hexadecimal-5e567e55ab28) interesting?